# Error when trying to intall Odoo app

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo, odoo-9, wizard

I created new module but can't install it from Odoo app store. When trying to do that I got an error:

```
      File "/opt/odoo/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_model.py", line 950, in xmlid_lookup
        raise ValueError('External ID not found in the system: %s' % (xmlid))
    ParseError: "External ID not found in the system: my_model.action_order_cancel" while parsing /home/pruf/addons/my_model/views/my_model_view.xml:6, near
    <record model="ir.ui.view" id="view_my_model_form">
```

My xml part:

```
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="view_my_model_form">
                <field name="name">my.model.form</field>
                <field name="model">my.model</field>
                <field name="arch" type="xml">
                    <form>
                    <header>
                        <button name="%(action_order_cancel)d" attrs="{'invisible': [('state','not in', ('to_approve_first', 'create_order'))]}" string="Cancel" groups="my_model.group_my__manager" type="action"/>
                        <button name="button_to_approve_first" states="draft" string="Request approval" type="object" class="oe_highlight" groups="my_model.group_my_model_user"/>
                        <button name="button_approved" states="to_approve_first" string="Approve" type="object" class="oe_highlight" groups="my_model.group_my_model_manager"/>
```

python code:

```
class PurchaseRequest(models.Model):
    _name = 'my.model'
    _inherit = ['mail.thread', 'ir.needaction_mixin']
    cancel_id = fields.One2many('order.cancel', 'my_model_id')



class OrderCancel(models.TransientModel):
    _name = 'order.cancel'
    my_model_id = fields.Many2one('my.model')
```

On action_order_cancel button click I am calling wizard.

My model structure:

```
__init__.py
__openerp__.py
models
----__init__.py
----my_model.py
security
----ir.model.access.csv
----my_model.xml
views
----my_model_view.xml
wizard
----__init__.py
----order.py
----order_view.xml
```

I can't find where the problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order of the XML does matter as its parsing the XML from Top to Bottom, you are referring to an action that is not yet parsed/declared

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what do I need to do.

Comment: You are trying to access my_model.action_order_cancel before its been loaded. Include all of the XML and it will be easier to help..

Comment: I have checked my __openerp__.py file
    "data": [
        ...........
        "views/my_module_view.xml",
        "wizard/reason_view.xml",
        ...........
    ],

changed places of these views and vuolia :)

Comment: Happy it's working for you :) .. Don't forget to accept the answer!

Answer (score 0):

it seems that `action_sale_order_cancel` is not available in your module.
If you use action of some other module you have to give a reference of that module

```
<button name="%(other_module_name.action_sale_order_cancel)d" attrs="{'invisible': [('state','not in', ('to_approve_first', 'create_order'))]}" string="Cancel" groups="my_model.group_my__manager" type="action"/>
```